# AWS VPC Peered - RDS accessing Active Directory Service

Tags: active-directory, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, vpc-peering

I have two aws accounts and I could establish a peering of two VPCs belonging to each account. Also, I was able to launch an EC2 instance one account joining to the AD domain on the other account. The problem is I can't find a way to do the same for RDS-SQL Server, I was trying to do it from AWS console.

This what I have configured on both accounts:

**AWS Account1**

- VPC1 - 172.32.0.0/16
- ADS1  - Active Directory Service is configured in this account

**AWS Account2**

- VPC2 172.33.0.0/16 - VPC2 is peered to VPC1
- EC2 launched and join ADS1
- RDS-SQL launched, but could not find a way to join ADS1

Please advise,

Comment: Is ADS1 an AWS MS Active Directory, or MS Active Directory Services ?

Answer (score 1):

This mode is not supported directly.

See:

[Using Windows Authentication with a Microsoft SQL Server DB Instance](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_SQLServerWinAuth.html)

Specifically:

> Windows Authentication is only supported for SQL Server DB instances in a VPC, and the DB instance must be in the same VPC as the directory.

However you could deploy a second AD instance into the same VPC as the RDS instance and establish a trust relationship at the AD level.

See:

[When to Create a Trust Relationship](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/directoryservice/latest/admin-guide/ms_ad_setup_trust.html)

Comment: Hi Alex, I did look at adding a second AD, but it is cost prohibitive for us at this point.